# Tauri blocks popups from 3rd party library

Tags: tauri, web3-react, trezor

I'm developing DApp with Tauri and trying to implement `@trezor/connect-web`.

However, somehow a popup is blocked when running it as a desktop app while it's properly opening on browsers. (There are no error messages in console)

[error message on Tauri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFZ4A.png)

It would be appreciated if you would let me know whether it would be opened by changing the configuration or implementation and how to do it.

The configuration I only updated is the below part in  `tauri.conf.json`.

```
    "allowlist": {
      "all": true
    },
```